# Drag elements and not select others

Tags: javascript, html

I have system to drag element (points) and map. When I drag points and mouse cursor is moving faster than new point rendering then map image is select.

I'd like skip this effect but I can't move this image to background because I need also drag this element.

[image: See an example]

I use ReactJS but this it's not important in this case.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with so little information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can programmatically use [`user-select: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select).

Or, alternatively, just rewrite the `selection`:

```css
.unselectable::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent; /* Gecko Browsers */
}

.unselectable::selection {
  background: transparent; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}

.us-none {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.pe-none {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<p>NORMAL! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam et explicabo iusto nemo nihil. Dicta dignissimos eius itaque nemo vero? Consequuntur ducimus hic ipsum nemo nesciunt, quia recusandae sapiente voluptate!</p>

<p class=unselectable>UNSELECTABLE! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam et explicabo iusto nemo nihil. Dicta dignissimos eius itaque nemo vero? Consequuntur ducimus hic ipsum nemo nesciunt, quia recusandae sapiente voluptate!</p>


<p class="us-none">USER SELECT NONE! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam et explicabo iusto nemo nihil. Dicta dignissimos eius itaque nemo vero? Consequuntur ducimus hic ipsum nemo nesciunt, quia recusandae sapiente voluptate!</p>

<p class="pe-none">POINTER EVENTS NONE! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam et explicabo iusto nemo nihil. Dicta dignissimos eius itaque nemo vero? Consequuntur ducimus hic ipsum nemo nesciunt, quia recusandae sapiente voluptate!</p>
```

[`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) makes the text still selectable on Chrome

Comment: Hitmands thanks, perfect solution. 

@PeterMader enough as you see. In image gif all problem was visible.